# What can cause a window.open to return "undefined"?

Tags: javascript

I have the following script in my Xul app:

```
MyClass = function() {
 this.go = function() {
  try {
   var scanWindow = window.open('chrome://test/content/scanWindow.xul','Scan','chrome, width=850, height=150, centerscreen');
   dump("scanWindow = " + scanWindow); // console output in Xul
  } catch(err) {
   dump("ERROR: " + err); // console output in Xul
  }
    }
}
```

when I call this method it prints

> scanWindow = undefined

Any hint on what can be causing that?

Comment: I'd say it's not defined because you never defined it.  You switched from goWindow to scanWindow.

Comment: @JacobM sorry, I corrected here. In my code this is correct.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Found out: what can cause this behavior is to re-write the window.open method, and return nothing. As it was done in another part of this code.

Comment: I don't understand what you are saying here.  Who is re-writing the window.open method?

Comment: @sydneyos "What can cause a window.open to return “undefined”?" is to Re-write the window.open method, and return nothing, is something that can cause this behavior. Me, or someone, did re-write it in another place.
(updating the answer to clarify)

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you can have spaces in the third argument to open.

Wrong:

`var scanWindow = window.open('chrome://test/content/scanWindow.xul','Scan','**chrome, width=850, height=150, centerscreen**');`

Correct:

```
var scanWindow = window.open('chrome://test/content/scanWindow.xul','Scan','**chrome,width=850,height=150,centerscreen**');
```

Comment: Hmm, this doesn't seem to be case anymore.  Should have verified before posting, sorry.

Answer (score 0):

```
var goWindow = window.open('chrome://test/content/go.xul','Go','chrome, width=850, height=150, centerscreen');
dump("scanWindow = " + scanWindow); // console output in Xul
```

your call to dump should be

```
dump("scanWindow = " + goWindow); // console output in Xul
```

Comment: sorry, I've writed it wrong here, but in my code is correct, it's not this the problem.. (I updated the question, thanks!)

Comment: can you try dump(window) to see if window is defined?

Comment: That prints "Chrome Window" just correctly. By the way, my `scanWindow` is opening, but for some reason the function returns undefined..

Comment: Obs. use "@Tom Brito:" so the comment will appear in my summary.. ;)